# How can one define a single parameter that is shared among layers of a neural network?

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose we have the following fully connected network:

```
class FC(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, imgsz=28, num_classes=10):
      super(FC, self).__init__()
      self.imgsz = imgsz
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(imgsz*imgsz, 300)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(300, 100)
      self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100, num_classes)
      self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

  def forward(self, x):
      x = x.view(-1, self.imgsz*self.imgsz)
      x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
      x = self.relu(self.fc2(x))
      x = self.fc3(x)
      
      return x
```

How can we define a single parameter using `nn.Parameter()` or any other methods that is shared among all layers?

Comment: which parameters do you want to be shared? There's no absolute shape matching in any of your layers, so the sharing will have to be partial.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your problem correctly this should solve your problem. Just add the parameters at initialisation.

```
class FC(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, imgsz=28, num_classes=10, hidden_layer_size_1= 300, hidden_layer_size_2= 100):
      super(FC, self).__init__()
      self.imgsz = imgsz
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(imgsz*imgsz, hidden_layer_size_1)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size_1, hidden_layer_size_2)
      self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size_2, num_classes)
      self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

  def forward(self, x):
      x = x.view(-1, self.imgsz*self.imgsz)
      x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
      x = self.relu(self.fc2(x))
      x = self.fc3(x)
      
      return x
```

Comment: No. This is not what I meant. You add arguments to the class. I want a parameter that is in fc1 as well as in fc2 and fc3.

Comment: What kind of parameters are we talking about? By adding the parameter to the class, you can initiate each layer with the definded parameter and have them share values.

Comment: Can you clarify which parameter you have added? then I will tell you what you are missing?

Comment: As an example I added the hidden layer sizes. And added them to the class.
If you look at the intialization of fc1, fc2, and fc3. They are created with the given parameter. Which is why I am wondering, which other parameters you would like to change. For your example, those are the only hard coded values, one could define as variables.